# Sum of Binomial Coefficients Times a Polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Is there a closed for expression for,

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}k^2$

It holds that,

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}k=n2^{n-1}$

Is there a generalization for higher degrees?

Comment: I would agree if the general case was addressed.

Comment: It is addressed in my answer (have a look at the end of it: I deal with $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}k^3$, too)

Comment: And in general $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}k^r = \frac{d^r}{dx^r}\left.\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}e^{kx}\right|_{x=0}$$

Comment: where the sum in the RHS equals $(1+e^x)^n$.

Answer (score 5):

**Binomial Coefficients as Polynomials**

Note that since
$$
\binom{k}{j}=\frac{k(k-1)\cdots(k-j+1)}{j!}\tag{1}
$$
$\binom{k}{j}$ can be viewed as a degree $j$ polynomial in $k$. We can write any degree $j$ polynomial in $k$ as a linear combination of $\binom{k}{0}$, $\binom{k}{1}$, $\dots$, $\binom{k}{j}$. For example,
$$
\begin{align}
1&=\binom{k}{0}\\
k&=\binom{k}{1}\\
k^2&=2\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}\\
\end{align}\tag{2}
$$

---

**Multiplying a Binomial Coefficient**
$$
\begin{align}
k\binom{k}{j}
&=\left[(j+1)\frac{k+1}{j+1}-1\right]\binom{k}{j}\tag{3a}\\
&=(j+1)\binom{k+1}{j+1}-\binom{k}{j}\tag{3b}\\
&=(j+1)\binom{k}{j+1}+(j+1)\binom{k}{j}-\binom{k}{j}\tag{3c}\\
&=(j+1)\binom{k}{j+1}+j\binom{k}{j}\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(3a)$: creative rewriting of $k$
$(3b)$: $\binom{k+1}{j+1}=\frac{k+1}{j+1}\binom{k}{j}$
$(3c)$: $\binom{k+1}{j+1}=\binom{k}{j+1}+\binom{k}{j}$
$(3d)$: algebra

---

**Applying $\boldsymbol{(3)}$**

We can recursively extend the list started in $(2)$:
$$
\begin{align}
k^3
&=k\cdot k^2\\
&=2k\binom{k}{2}+k\binom{k}{1}\\
&=2\left(3\binom{k}{3}+2\binom{k}{2}\right)+\left(2\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}\right)\\
&=6\binom{k}{3}+6\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
k^4
&=k\cdot k^3\\
&=6k\binom{k}{3}+6k\binom{k}{2}+k\binom{k}{1}\\
&=6\left(4\binom{k}{4}+3\binom{k}{3}\right)+6\left(3\binom{k}{3}+2\binom{k}{2}\right)+\left(2\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}\right)\\
&=24\binom{k}{4}+36\binom{k}{3}+14\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

---

**How This Helps**

Once we have written the polynomial as a linear combination of binomial coefficients, we can use the following formula to simplify the final sums:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{j}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{j}\binom{n-j}{k-j}\\
&=\binom{n}{j}2^{n-j}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Application to the Question**

We can apply the formulas derived above to get the following generalizations

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k^2
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(2\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}\right)\\
> &=2\binom{n}{2}2^{n-2}+\binom{n}{1}2^{n-1}\\
> &=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2^{n-1}\left(\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}\right)}\tag{7}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k^3
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(6\binom{k}{3}+6\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}\right)\\
> &=6\binom{n}{3}2^{n-3}+6\binom{n}{2}2^{n-2}+\binom{n}{1}2^{n-1}\\
> &=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2^{n-2}\left(3\binom{n}{3}+6\binom{n}{2}+2\binom{n}{1}\right)}\tag{8}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k^4
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(24\binom{k}{4}+36\binom{k}{3}+14\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}\right)\\
> &=24\binom{n}{4}2^{n-4}+36\binom{n}{3}2^{n-3}+14\binom{n}{2}2^{n-2}+\binom{n}{1}2^{n-1}\\
> &=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2^{n-1}\left(3\binom{n}{4}+9\binom{n}{3}+7\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}\right)}\tag{9}
> \end{align}
> $$

The formulas above can be extended to give formulas for as high a degree polynomial as one wishes.

---

**Using Stirling Numbers**

[Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) allows us to easily write monomials as linear combinations of binomial coefficients with the following formula
$$
\newcommand{\stirtwo}[2]{\left\{{#1}\atop{#2}\right\}}
k^j=\sum_{i=0}^ji!\stirtwo{j}{i}\binom{k}{i}\tag{10}
$$
Summing, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k^jx^k
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^ji!\stirtwo{j}{i}\binom{k}{i}x^k\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^ji!\stirtwo{j}{i}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i}x^k\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^ji!\stirtwo{j}{i}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{k-i}x^k\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{(1+x)^n\sum_{i=0}^ji!\stirtwo{j}{i}\binom{n}{i}\left(\frac x{1+x}\right)^i}\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
Formulas $(7)$-$(9)$ can be derived from $(11)$ by setting $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

For a different solution for a general case that the given by @JackD'Aurizio you want to transform the polynomial $p(k)$ in the expression

$$\sum_k\binom{n}{k}p(k)$$

in a polynomial based in [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). By example

$$\sum_k\binom{n}{k}k^2=\sum_k\binom{n}{k}(k^{\underline{2}}+k)$$

Then the binomial sum can be simplified extracting falling factorials of $n$ out of the summation and (probably) changing the index of the sums.

To pass from $p(k)$ to a "polynomial" of falling factorials you will need to know that

$$k^n=\sum_j \left\{{ n\atop j }\right\}k^{\underline j}$$

for $n\ge 0$, where the symbols $\left\{{ n\atop j }\right\}$ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

[This link](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/polyToFac.htm) have an easy algorithm to pass an entire polynomial to a "polynomial" of falling factorials.

Answer (score 2):

For the factor $k$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}k=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}k
=n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}\\
=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n\choose k}=n2^{n-1}.$$

Similarly for $(k-1)k$,

$$\sum_{k=2}^n {n\choose k}(k-1)k=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}(k-1)k=(n-1)n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-2)!}{(n-k)!(k-2)!}\\
=(n-1)n\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} {n\choose k}=(n-1)n2^{n-2}.$$

More generally,

$$\sum_{k=m}^n {n\choose k}(k-m+1)\cdots(k-1)k\\
=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}(k-m+1)\cdots(k-1)k\\
=(n-m+1)\cdots(n-1)n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-m)!}{(n-k)!(k-m)!}\\
=(n-1)n\sum_{k=0}^{n-m} {n\choose k}=(n-m+1)(n-1)n2^{n-m}.$$

Then,

$$k^2=(k-1)k+k,\\
k^3=(k-2)(k-1)k+3k^2-2k=(k-2)(k-1)k+3(k-1)k+k\\
\cdots$$
and you can convert any polynomial to a sum of falling factorials.

Notice that the $m$ first terms in the summations must be added separately.